# Where does Neo4J writes configuration with 'dump_configuration=true'?

Tags: neo4j

I've added `dump_configuration=true` to my `neo4j.properties` file but couldn't find the effective configuration written anywhere.

The terminal where I run `bin/neo4j start` from is empty and the `data/log/console.log` file shows that the web interface is ready but no additional prints.

Does anyone know where is it written to?

Answer (score 0):

According source code of Neo4j it should be printed to stdout.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/4540b18f95e7eddd1cbc36c990c852962175755a/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/unsafe/batchinsert/BatchInserterImpl.java#L1135